# How can I open and lauch .pdf files in desktop using my App

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8.1

i use the following code.

```
<Extensions>
   <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
       <FileTypeAssociation Name="pdf">
           <SupportedFileTypes>
              <FileType>.pdf</FileType>
            </SupportedFileTypes>
        </FileTypeAssociation>
    </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

How can i get options as open with my app like open with pdf reader. Then how can I bring it inside myapp using launcher,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var f = args.Files[0];
            var c = args.Files[0].Name;
            string path = args.Files[0].Path;
        }